# Unable to create Windows system environment variable

Tags: windows, qt, environment-variables

I want to create my own Windows System Environment variable but I'm not able to make my app do it.
I've tried different solutions but none of them worked. Or worked only for those seconds while my app run.
This one should work:

```
QProcessEnvironment qpeInfo = QProcessEnvironment::systemEnvironment();

qpeInfo.insert( "MyEnvName", "TestValue" );
```

or this:

```
system( QString( "set MyEnvName=Testvalue" ).toStdString().c_str() );
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for environment variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682653.aspx) tells you how to do this:

> Calling `SetEnvironmentVariable` has no effect on the system environment variables. To programmatically add or modify system environment variables, add them to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` registry key, then broadcast a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message with `lParam` set to the string `"Environment"`. This allows applications, such as the shell, to pick up your updates.

Comment: Sorry ... almost sleeping, my brain is in sleep mode: how can I broadcast message in Qt?

Comment: `SendMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, ...)`

Comment: @bukkfa: applications often need to set transient environment variables, so there is an API to do it.  Applications hardly ever need to change the permanent environment variables, so Microsoft probably don't think it's worth the cost of building an API, particularly when there is already a supported solution.  Also, the current approach makes it less likely that developers will make permanent changes to the environment by mistake.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: thanks for your comment. Basically I agree with you. Developers, I mean application should not modify the sytem environment variables. But sometimes there is a need to create/modify/delete Global Environment variables and dont forget about modification of 'PATH' system environment variable. This is an important part if you make your own installer application. This is why I'd like to raised the question.
But of course I can live with this approach and I should withdraw the 'idiot way' comment.